# Resources for performance statistics of trading systems

Tags: resource

I'm looking for an online resource to study the usual performance statistics (CAGR, MaxDD, Payoff Ratio, Win/Loss Ratio, etc.) of trading systems, preferably trend-following systems.

I know that [Collective2](http://collective2.com/)
 is a great resource for trading systems and their performance statistics...but are there also any other useful websites offering these kind of data?

Comment: With 'successful trading systems' I see 2 difficulties: 1) 'successful' is debatetable and depends on your definition (is a year of non-negative returns enough, although ultimately you lost 75% in 3 years?) 2) I believe truely successful strategies are not disclosed and those that are, might suffer from survivorship bias. Maybe looking at (hedge) fund performances would be a viable alternative, although survivorship bias might apply as well.

Comment: Just removed "successful" from the title, I agree that's a pretty subjective matter ;)

Comment: It's just monthly data, but maybe state of trend following is of interest to you. There are monthly posts at least for a couple of years. see http://www.automated-trading-system.com/state-of-trend-following-in-september/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, [Wealth Lab](http://www.wealth-lab.com/Charting/Strategies/Default.aspx?id=gKDpXpVy81Vq3g3Dz8jVELPmHEf1H/WdfgCeS3SsdHTtI4OmdcIziEAoFucRQ3E9) used to have rankings and scores. Maybe it is only for registered users now.

[Portfolio123](http://www.portfolio123.com/app/opener/ptf) also has systems with rankings, but you definitely have to be a member to see them.

[Equametrics](http://equametrics.com) also has algorithmic trading systems with free signups.